# jQuery: onclick, change from true to false

Tags: jquery

I have this right now:

```
$('#markAll').live('click', function () {
checkAll(true, $('.cbPick'));
$('#markAll').text("");
$('#markAll').prepend("<strong>Unmark all</strong>");
});
```

When i press #markAll, it marks every checkbox with .cbPick, and then it changes the text from (previous "Mark all") to "Unmark alL". Now if you press again on "unmark all" nothing happens. And i wish to if you click on "Unmark all" then it should do:

```
checkAll(false, $('.cbPick'));
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var marked = false;
$('#markAll').live('click', function () {
    marked = (marked)? false: true;
    checkAll(marked, $('.cbPick'));
    $('#markAll').text("");
    $('#markAll').prepend("<strong>Unmark all</strong>");
});
```

Comment: You forgot to change true to marked. It works fine now. Although when i press on the unmarked i also want it to say "mark all" again.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following:

```
$('#markAll').live('click', function () {
    checkAll(true, $('.cbPick'));
    $('#markAll').text("");
    var unmarkAll = $('<strong>Unmark all</strong>');
    unmarkall.click(function(){ checkAll(false, $('.cbPick')); });
    $('#markAll').prepend(unmarkall);
});
```

This just creates the new 'Unmark all' as a jquery object and adds a click function to it before prepending it to the markall object.

This would probably still cause problems though as the markall event and the unmarkall event would fire at the same time because the unmarkall object is prepended inside the markall object. You'd be better off using the `.before` function instead of `.prepend`. then hiding the markall link.